# How can I return a JArray from a [WebMethod] using Json.NET?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json.net, webmethod

Is it possible to return a `JArray` object from a `[WebMethod]` using jQuery ajax and Json.NET?  Example:

```
[WebMethod]
public JArray GetJsonData()
{
    JArray jArray = new JArray();
    JObject jObject = new JObject();
    jObject.Add(new JProperty("name", "value"));
    jArray.Add(jObject);
    return jArray;
}
```

When I call this using jQuery ajax, it returns something that looks like this:

`[[[[]]]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to return a string.

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetJsonData()
{
    JArray jArray = new JArray();
    JObject jObject = new JObject();
    jObject.Add(new JProperty("name", "value"));
    jArray.Add(jObject);
    return jArray.ToString();
}
```

Comment: The only reason I don't want to return a string is because then I will have to parse it in javascript because of how .NET wraps the `.d` property around the result.

Comment: While this does work, I don't like all of the spaces and carriage returns it adds to the JSON.  Looking at it in Postman, it's pretty ugly compared to normal JSON structured output you get from not returning a string.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my `$.get()` to a `$.getJSON()`, and my backend to:

```
[HttpGet]
public JArray GetJSON(string id)
{
    JArray items = Populate(id);
    return items;
}
```